# Is it possible to change the OMPL source code for the V-Rep plug-in?

Tags: robotics, motion-planning

I develop motion planning algorithms using ompl and I'm wondering if I can somehow change the V-Rep ompl plug-in so it runs my own ompl planning algorithms (like replace RRT-Connect, FMT,... etc with my own algorithms)?

How should I have do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add a new planner in OMPL. OMPL is installed from source.

1. Add the source code of the planner to `ompl/src/ompl/geometric/planners` just like all the other planners.
2. Regenerate CMake related files and make. In `ompl/build/Release/`, do 
   `cmake . ../..` then `make -j4`
3. Include the header file of your custom planner wherever needed.